# Puppet manifests file which is running fine on windows 7, returning error on windows server 2008

Tags: puppet, puppet-enterprise

I am working on the puppet manifests file to install and upgrade few of the application on the windows machine. 
The code I have made is doing exactly what I wanted on the windows 7 machine, but when the same code is running on the windows server 2008 machine, it is returning following error:

```
 Error: Could not prefetch package provider 'windows': Type 0 is not supported.
Error: /Stage[main]/Main/Package[Apache Tomcat 7.0 Tomcat7 (remove only)]: Coul
 not evaluate: Type 0 is not supported.
Error: /Stage[main]/Main/Package[Java 8 Update 92 (64-bit)]: Could not evaluate
 Type 0 is not supported.
Error: /Stage[main]/Main/Package[Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.1]: Could not eva
uate: Type 0 is not supported.
```

Here is the code I am running

```
package { 'Java 8 Update 92 (64-bit)' :
        ensure => installed,
        source => 'C:\ProgramData\PuppetLabs\temp\jdk-8u92-windows-x64.exe',
        install_options => ['/s',{ 'INSTALLDIR' => 'C:\opt\java' }],
        provider => windows
```

}

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: I have added the code above.

Comment: Try commenting out provider from the resources.

Comment: Yes I did that earlier but didn't work